# Servlet error :- 404 Not Found using HTML WEB FORM DATA

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

I have created a Servlet using GENERIC SERVLET which is working fine on port 8080
**But now i have CREATED another html web form file to accept the input parameters from users,
and then i created a Register Servlet(for that to accept the parameters from html page) using get parameter() method, and so that this file can accept the web form data, but when i made my request through html form data, it should accept the parameters and show the results, but instead , 
it says** 
"404 Not Found" Intellij Idea..
I'm using Tomcat as a webserver

PLEASE HELP ME, Iam including some screenshots and program code..

Program code for HTML :-
[MY HTML CODE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7tUw.jpg)

[MY DIRECTORY IN INTELIJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjnHC.jpg)

[MY SERVLET CODE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjEjd.jpg)

[HTML PAGE TO ACCEPT USER FORM DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCXI3.jpg)

[404 NOT FOUND ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mzow.jpg)

**MAY BE I don't know how to manage ports ?..**

Comment: but why is this html working on port 63342 and swiiching to port 8080 because servlet is defined in that port ? WTL ?  What the logic ?!!

Answer (score 1):

Your post url is wrong.  It should be /yoyo/web/Userinfoservlet instead of just /Userinfoservlet

Comment: Sorry actually the file should be for Register html file, now i have update the image, But giving the path as /yoyo/web/Register isn't working

Comment: actually the file Register servlet was listening to port 8080 and the html file was forcing to go to the invalid url

Answer (score 0):

done !, i just changed the url to **localhost:8080/Register** and it works !

**actually the file Register servlet was listening to port 8080 and the html file was forcing to go to the invalid url –**